# Find the value of segment $AD$ in the triangle inscribed below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

O $\triangle ABC$ is inscribed in a circle with center $O$. Through $B$ we draw $BD ⊥ AO$, which meets $AC$ in $D$. A$B = 6$ and $AC = 9$. Calculate $AD$. (S:$AD=4$)

[image]

I try

$2R.BC =BG.AC+AB.CG \implies 2R.BC = 9BG+6CG$

$\triangle ABG: BG^2 = 4R^2-36$

$\triangle ACG: CG^2 = 4R^2 - 81$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angle $\widehat{OAB}=\widehat{OBA}$ is
$\frac 12(180^\circ-2\hat C)=90^\circ-\hat C$.
So $\widehat{ABD}=\hat C$, making $\widehat{ADB}=\hat B$. The two triangles are thus similar:
$$\Delta ABC\sim\Delta ADB\qquad
\text{ which gives }
\frac{AB}{AD} 
=
\frac{AC}{AB} 
\ .
$$
The missing segment is the yellow one in the equality: $6^2=9\cdot \bbox[yellow]4$.